# Application running in ASP.NET is not giving the desired output

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application not calculating the percentage correctly. It is suppose to calculate the input in percent. But there is bug somewhere which is preventing it from doing so.

For example, if I input any number starting with decimals like `0.01` or `0.001` or `0.02` etc it will give me the output `1`, `0.1` and `2` respectively. If I punch in any whole numbers like `1`, `2`, `3`, `10`, etc, it will always give the same output i.e `0.01`.

This application was done by some contractors 5 years ago. The main in-charge of this application has left. Which leaves me and my little experience in c# and asp.net in figuring out the issue. Before I seek any further help, I thought I should ask geniuses out there and see what they have to say, may be I will end up figuring out the issue with your help. I did talk to other IT people in my department, they guess it might be because of the code below.

```
    if (int.TryParse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtminup.Text) ? "0" : txtminup.Text, out n))
```

I am not 100% sure how to debug or find the issue. If anyone can point me out anything that might help or provide me some resources that I can look it up, it will be really helpful. I have copied few of the lines of code. I can provide more information but don't know which one will be more relevant.

```
    protected string MinUp
{
    get
    {
        return (string)ViewState["minup"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["minup"] = value;
    }
}
```

==============

```
  MinUp = rows["process_minimum_up"].ToString();
                        PIMSSource = rows["pims_source"].ToString();
                        //MinUp = Convert.ToDouble()
                        if (MinUp != string.Empty || MinUp.Length > 0)
                        {
                            MinUp = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(MinUp) * 100);
                        }
```

=====================

```
    if (DCFoption != "P")
        {
            MinUp = "";
        }

        if (DcfmSeq != "0")
        {
            int caret;
            caret = ddlvbcfmseq.SelectedValue.IndexOf("^");
            DcfmSeq = DcfmSeq.Substring(0, caret);
        }

        if (DCFoption != "P" && ddlpdwnlst.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
        {
            MinUp = "";
        }

        if (PIMSTagId == "Not specified")
        {
            PIMSTagId = "";
        }

        if (MinUp != string.Empty || MinUp.Length > 0)
        {
            int n;
            if (int.TryParse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtminup.Text) ? "0" : txtminup.Text, out n))
            {
                MinUp = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(MinUp) / 100);
                if (Convert.ToInt32(MinUp) < 0)
                {
                    MinUp = "0";
                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(MinUp) > 1)
                {
                    MinUp = "1";
                }
            }
        }

        if ((DCFoption == string.Empty || DCFoption.Length < 1) || DCFoption == "D")
        {
            MinUp = "";
        }

        if (MinUp != string.Empty || MinUp.Length > 0)
        {
            int n;
            if (int.TryParse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtminup.Text) ? "0" : txtminup.Text, out n))
            {
              if (Convert.ToDouble(MinUp) <= 0)
              {
                  MinUp = ".0001";
              }
            }
        }
```

=======================

```
    if (rdbProcess.Checked == true && (txtminup.Text == string.Empty || txtminup.Text.Length < 1) && ddlpdwnlst.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
                                                            {
                                                                Utilities.ShowAlert(this.Page, Resources.Resource.RIPimsUpload_MinUptime.ToString());
                                                                txtminup.Focus();
```

======================

```
    int n;
                                                                        if (!int.TryParse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRound.Text) ? "0" : txtRound.Text, out n))
                                                                        {
                                                                            Utilities.ShowAlert(this.Page, Resources.Resource.RIPimsUpload_RoundingNum.ToString());
                                                                        }
                                                                        else if (!IsDouble(txtminup.Text))
```

======================

```
    try
    {
        DBResults objDBResult = new DBResults();
        WEIS.RIPimsUpload objRI = new WEIS.RIPimsUpload();
        objDBResult = objRI.SaveItemInsert(reciseq, shortname, name, eiscprocess2, period, media, euseq, eqmtseq, eiscuom, pollseq, dcfmseq, rounding, formula, physmin, physmax, warn1min, warn1max, warn2min, warn2max, pimsStatus, pimsTagidp, datapoint, freq, periodoffset, initpimstTagId, initDataPoint, initLoadFrequency, initperiodoffset, day0result, retention, audituser, dcfoption, minup, pimssource);

        if (objDBResult.oraErrMsg.Trim().ToString().Length > 1)
        {
            Exception ex = new Exception(objDBResult.oraErrMsg.ToString());
            throw ex;
        }

        return objDBResult.oraIntReturn;
    }
```

===============================

```
    protected int SaveItemUpdate(int reciseq, string shortname, string name, int eiscprocess2, int period, int media, int euseq, int eqmtseq, int eiscuom, int pollseq, int dcfmseq, string rounding, string formula, string physmin, string physmax, string warn1min, string warn1max, string warn2min, string warn2max, string pimsStatus, string pimsTagidp, string datapoint, string freq, char periodoffset, string initpimstTagId, char initDataPoint, char initLoadFrequency, char initperiodoffset, string day0result, string retention, string audituser, string dcfoption, string minup, string pimssource)
{
    try
    {
        DBResults objDBResult = new DBResults();
        WEIS.RIPimsUpload objRI = new WEIS.RIPimsUpload();
        objDBResult = objRI.SaveItemUpdate(reciseq, shortname, name, eiscprocess2, period, media, euseq, eqmtseq, eiscuom, pollseq, dcfmseq, rounding, formula, physmin, physmax, warn1min, warn1max, warn2min, warn2max, pimsStatus, pimsTagidp, datapoint, freq, periodoffset, initpimstTagId, initDataPoint, initLoadFrequency, initperiodoffset, day0result, retention, audituser, dcfoption, minup, pimssource);

        if (objDBResult.oraErrMsg.Trim().ToString().Length > 1)
        {
            Exception ex = new Exception(objDBResult.oraErrMsg.ToString());
            throw ex;
        }
```

=============================

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        lblUserMsgText.Text = "";
        bool dcfm = ddlvbcfmseq.Enabled;
        string minup, dcfoption="";

        minup = txtminup.Text;

        if (rdbNone.Checked == true)
        {
            dcfoption = "NONE";
        }
        else if (rdbProcess.Checked == true)
        {
            dcfoption = "P";
        }
        else if (rdbData.Checked == true)
        {
            dcfoption = "D";
        }

        Index = Convert.ToInt32(rdbListradios.SelectedIndex);

        SaveItem();

        RetainClientControlValues(dcfm, dcfoption, minup);
    }
```

==============================

```
    protected void btnExcMod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        lblUserMsgText.Text = "";
        bool dcfm = ddlvbcfmseq.Enabled;
        string minup, dcfoption = "";
        Index = Convert.ToInt32(rdbListradios.SelectedIndex);
        minup = txtminup.Text;

        if (rdbNone.Checked == true)
        {
            dcfoption = "NONE";
        }
        else if (rdbProcess.Checked == true)
        {
            dcfoption = "P";
        }
        else if (rdbData.Checked == true)
        {
            dcfoption = "D";
        }

        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        int evntseq = Convert.ToInt32(btn.CommandArgument.ToString());

        RetainClientControlValues(dcfm, dcfoption, minup);
        //Response.Write("you clicked on button");
    }
```

Comment: what is the issue? what do you want us to do? please explain more

Comment: is this the only part of the code doing calculations?

Comment: It sounds like the numbers are being multiplied by 100 somewhere (you wrote, "decimals like 0.01 or 0.001 or 0.02 etc it will give me the output 1, 0.1 and 2 "). Look for suchlike code.

Comment: what is the output supposed to be when you enter a number?

Comment: Yes, it is being multiplied 'if (MinUp != string.Empty || MinUp.Length > 0)
                            {
                                MinUp = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(MinUp) * 100);
                            }'

Comment: Post the rest of the code where they are multiplied, it helps to see the higher ground as well

Comment: Yes, it is being multiplied 'if (MinUp != string.Empty || MinUp.Length > 0)
                            {
                                MinUp = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(MinUp) * 100);
                            }'               I am looking for more places where it has been used. When I first input the number let say 0.1 should give me 0.001 and when after saved it will turn back and should give me 0.1. Bare with me here, I am using this website for first time not sure how to put codes here in comments, I will put all the pieces together where it has been used and post it here.

Comment: Could you give us the rest of the code as this wouldn't even be a fair example to try as `n` is the Parsed value that is never used!

Comment: It looks as though percentages are being represented in two ways. One without the _%_ symbol `0.01` and also with an implicit _%_ as `1 (%)`. Is this an actual calculation function or a display formatting function?

Comment: @A.Pasa If the code that you have listed here has to convert a whole num into decimal you should use something like this Convert.ToString((float)Convert.ToInt32(MinUp) / 100) instead Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(MinUp) / 100)

Comment: I haven't tried float yet but I did change it to double but it didn't do anything. I don't think it is the client side error so, it has to do something with these codes. I will ask my supervisor if these codes can go to githup so that you have better understanding of the issue. I already see lots of responses and willingness to help. I really appreciate this guys. This is the first time I am using this website and I am impressed by it and impressed by all of your knowledge.

Comment: Unfortunately, i am not allowed to have these codes on github :). Any idea on what the issue is or any other way recommendation, suggestion to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Umamaheswaran thanks for the hint.

```
    int n;
    if (int.TryParse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtminup.Text) ? "0" : txtminup.Text, out n))
```

Above was the initial code and i changed it to

```
     double n;
    if (double.TryParse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtminup.Text) ? "0" : txtminup.Text, out n))
```

and also whereever it was converting to

```
   Convert.ToInt32
```

I changed it to

```
    Convert.ToDouble
```

I don't know whatever was the issue as I am not very much familiar with asp.net and c# but changing above code solved the issue. Now whenever I input a number it will change to percentage and save it to correct format.

Thank you all for your help and concern. I have few more different issues. I will try to solve it if not I will post it here and try to be concise and to the point.